# Where is com.google.api.services.tasks.TasksRequest?

Tags: android, google-api, google-tasks-api, google-tasks

I'm trying to install this Google sample project (tasks-android-sample): http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/tasks-android-sample/instructions.html

...but I'm getting unresolved classes. The project comes with jars but doesn't say which ones to include (in typical Google fashion) so through experimentation I managed to resolve most of the classes except these two:

```
import com.google.api.services.tasks.TasksRequest;
import com.google.api.services.tasks.model.Task;
```

Does anyone know which jars have these classes? I included **every** jar that came with the project, and set my target to Google APIs 8 as instructed by the docs (I tried other targets as well) but I can't resolve these classes.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, the whole project build/release life cycle is managed by Maven. the two import statements in the question is from **google-api-services-tasks** library.

You can find the latest version of jar file with source and javadoc at [here](http://mavenrepo.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/com/google/apis/google-api-services-tasks/v1-rev2-1.4.0-beta/).

If you use Maven, add the following to your pom.xml:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>google-api-services</id>
    <url>http://mavenrepo.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>

... ...

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-tasks</artifactId>
    <version>v1-rev2-1.4.0-beta</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Note that the com.google.api.services.tasks.TasksRequest is introduced since version v1-1.3.0-beta-SNAPSHOT.